# div not floating inside parent div with display inline-block

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, width

I want to make both child divs to be inline inside the red box

```css
.parent {
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="float : left">
    <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div style="float : left">
    <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle** : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8erreo/)

using `Float : left` and `Display : inline-block` on child div does not work. while using `display : flex` breaks the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `img` is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) with its own intrinsic dimensions:

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model. Typical replaced elements are:
>   `<iframe>`,`<video>`,`<embed>`,`<img>`.

and:

> CSS handles replaced elements specifically in some cases, like when
>   calculating margins and some auto values.

Note that if there is a text here instead of an image, it works as desired:

```css
.parent {
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="float : left">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div style="float : left">
    Text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution**:

So the solution is to specify the dimesions of the container for the `replaced element` here.

So give a width to the `.parent div` and put `max-width: 100%` for the `img` to fill `.parent div` like this:

```css
.parent {
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
.parent div img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="float : left">
    <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div style="float : left">
    <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your elements are actually floating, the problem is that if you inspect your child divs you'll see that their widths are 100% so it seems like they're not floating, instead of giving `width:30%` to images you must give it to their parent (the child divs) and `width:100%` to the images. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8erreo/5/)**

```
.parent {
  width : 35%;
    height : 200px;
    background-color : red;
    display : inline-block;
    margin : 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  display : inline-block;
  width:30%;
}
```

Comment: thanks, your code is so simple and easy to read, but I still need to understand the explanation

Comment: oh I finally understand, so the problem is I didn't specify the `width` of the `div` in which the `img` placed, so by default the `div width` is 100%, it doesn't matter if the `img width` is 30% of its `div` because the `div` itself is occupying the whole red box

Comment: that is exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Looking something like this

```css
.parent {
  width : 35%;
 height : 200px;
 background-color : red;
 display : inline-block;
 margin : 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div >
    <img width=100% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div >
  <img width=100% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `float: left;` from `.parent div` and change `.parent div` styling `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;`

```css
.parent {
  width : 35%;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : red;
  display : inline-block;
  margin : 30px auto
}
.parent div {
  display : inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <img width=30% src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you.
I have added

> .parent div {
>        width: 100%; }

and

> .parent div img { width:50%; float:left; }

```css
.parent {
  width : 35%;
 height : 200px;
 background-color : red;
 display : inline-block;
 margin : 30px auto
}
.parent div {
     width: 100%;
}
.parent div img{width:50%;float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <img  src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
    <div>
  <img src="http://assets.bmdstatic.com/assets/Data/image_product_500x500/CANON--SKU10516586-2016926135639.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```